# Having two spans on same line take all available space proportionally to their width

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to have two spans on the same line so that:

1. If they overflow, ellipsis are added.
2. The wider one takes more space than the smaller one.
3. Both spans' width (and their parent) are variable.

You see in the code below that (2) and (3) are problematic because they don't take all available space.

Thanks in advance!

```css
.box {
  border: solid 1px #444;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
li {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: solid 1px #def;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: #dfefff;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.name {
  color: #259;
}
.email {
  color: #581;
}
.name,
.email {
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <ol>
    <li><span class="name">Demetrius Washington Montgomery McGollinghgrahham</span>
      <span class="email">demetrius.washington@gmail.com</span>
    </li>
    <li><span class="name">James</span>
      <span class="email">demetrius.washington.also.james.lomg@gmail.com</span>
    </li>
    <li><span class="name">Demetrius Washington Montgomery McGollinghgrahham</span>
      <span class="email">a@b.com</span>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: I am just confirming the problem which you are saying. In the 2 one has the space to display text but it has not displaying the text fully?.

Comment: Correct. Similar to (3), it has space but it doesn't show it fully.

Comment: The text has not display fully because of the `max-width`(50%) you have written in the `.name,.email`class . If the text has bigger that is displaying only in 50% width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did 2 changes in your code. Added a display property to the `<li>` to flexbox. change the `max-width` of the `.name, .email` from `50%` to `100%`. Please see the updated code below.

```
li {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: solid 1px #def;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: #dfefff;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: flex; 
}

.email {
  color: #581;
  margin-left:5px;
}

.name,
.email {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

See the [Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaqpdR)

Comment: Thanks, Fazil! Is there a way to make this work (ugh, I know) on IE8 and IE9? I'm accepting the answer because it is what I need, but I'm curious (I'm trying something along the lines of display: table-cell). 

And thanks again!

Comment: Thanks Oscar.  Flexbox doesn't support in IE9 and it earlier versions. So you can use a different set of style exclusively for the IE versions . The syntax would be like the following.

`<!--[if IE]>
            <style>
                li {display: table-cell;}
            </style>
<![endif]-->`